# Python is there a way to align my text along and truncate float at the same time

Tags: python, alignment

I'm trying to find out if in the format function if I can convert my float to 2 decimal points and have it align in the one line. In the example below I want to align the last element, i'm wondering if I can do something like `print("{0:.2f} {1:<60} {{2:.2f}:<8} {3:.2f}".format(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3]))` I'm aware I can use the round function on the 2nd last element and then align it.

```
item1 = 0.312, "longname2", 123.6, 76.4329
item2 = 0.112, "longname3", 12.6, 12
arr = [item, item1, item2]
for item in arr:
  print("{0:.2f} {1:<60} {2:.2f} {3:.2f}".format(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by changing the number of spaces between the 2nd and 3rd element of `i` depending on the number of digits in the 3rd element:

```
item1 = 0.312, "longname2", 123.6, 76.4329
item2 = 0.112, "longname3", 12.6, 12
arr = [item1, item2]
for i in arr:
  print(f"{i[0]:.2f} {i[1]:<{63-len(str(i[2]))}} {i[2]:.2f} {i[3]:.2f}")
```

Output:

```
0.31 longname2                                                  123.60 76.43
0.11 longname3                                                   12.60 12.00
```